# Connect to Linux device using 4G connection and dynamic IP address

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, remote-access

Not sure where to ask my question.

I might have many hundred Linux devices, each device uses a 4G connection to connect the Internet and each of them have SSH service running at port 22 and a dynamic IP address.

My question is how do I use SSH to connect to each of them?

Do I need to have them in a VPN?

Comment: Abandon the idea of interactive access to any specific device. You'll want an agent on the device that picks up instructions/commands/settings from the management server and that will post back it's health and any results/collected data. It would be useful for an on-site operator to have confirmation the device is indeed communicating with your management server or in error.
Your devices need to phone home.
You'll want your devices to connect to your management server(s) and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

In my case,  I had several base stations to connect to the core network. I used openvpn. Openvpn server in the core and generated openvpn client certificates and installed them in the other devices.

Answer (score 2):

With hundreds of endpoints that may or may not be available at various times - and with the added complication of ISPs possibly putting devices behind CGNAT or blocking inbound connections in other ways, you really don't want to risk using a solution that's dependent on calling out to each individual device.

Instead you should probably do the exact opposite of what you describe, like @HermanB wrote:

Set up a central web service your devices can contact to report their status and/or fetch their configs.

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/introducing-secure-tunneling-for-aws-iot-device-management-a-new-secure-way-to-troubleshoot-iot-devices/

Yes I agree with @HermanB , but somecase if we need more investigation 
I ask AWS and this seems to be another good solution

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a dynamic IP solution like [duckdns](https://duckdns.org), it has an android setting so even if your IP is changin all the time you can have an static address